# How to organize a dataset with many attributes

Tags: algorithms, categorical-data, classification

I have a set of data which consists of many different types (measurable, categorical)
For example:
name   measurable_attribute_1   categorical_attribute_1   measurable_attribute_2   categorical_attribute_2 ...

Number of attributes may grows quite quickly during my study: into my spreadsheet, I can as many new entries as attribute... I have about a hundred of entries in this classification scheme, about 70 attribute, so far, and I am at the beginning of my data collection.

I would like to perform statistical analysis of this data set. For example, what are the common features of the entries that have a similar categorical_attribute and this range of values of measurable_attribute.

Well, I would like to generate relationships between attributes in order to create training images. 
However, I am not sure of how to organize the data prior to classification. Even though, should I organize the data?... (referring to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47/clustering-of-large-heavy-tailed-dataset))

Also, I can hardly gather entries into classes.

I do not want to introduce any bias obviously.

I am also quite new to statistical analysis (but eager to learn).

Answer (score 1):

One option would involve using **optimal scaling principal components analysis**.
The approach allows you to state your measurement assumptions about each variable (e.g., nominal, ordinal, numeric).
I've used it in SPSS: see the Categories Add-On module (i.e., Analyze - Dimension Reduction - Optimal Scaling).
I'm not sure, but the homals package in R may also implement the procedure.

A quick Google ( http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=optimal+scaling+principal+components) 
revealed this reference:
http://takane.brinkster.net/Yoshio/p009.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Exploratory Factor Analysis. It will tell you which attributes are the most similar to each other.